# Evaluating $\sqrt[3]{100^2\cdot 97+299}$ with clever algebra

Tags: algebra-precalculus, radicals

We can evaluate $\sqrt[3]{100^2\cdot 97+299}$ as follow,

$$\sqrt[3]{100^2\cdot 97+299}=\sqrt[3]{100^2\cdot(100-3)+3\cdot 100-1}=\sqrt[3]{100^3-3\cdot 100^2+3\cdot 100-1}=99$$
But I'm wondering is it possible to evaluate the expression with clever algebra differently?

Comment: $$n^2(n-3)+3n-1=\cdots=(n-1)^3$$

Comment: 1. You should replace the "." by "$\cdot$" using the command ```\cdot``` for better formatting.
2. You should look up [binomial theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_theorem).

Comment: This is clever and is clearly the intended approach.  Why do you think there should be anything different?

Comment: @RossMillikan True, But I saw many math problems  on this site that got different elegant answers. So I thought maybe there are other approaches for this problem too.

Comment: If you want to show the algebraic rewriting explicitly add additional steps towards the end of the form $\sqrt[3]{n^3+3\cdot n^2\cdot(-1)+3\cdot n\cdot(-1)^2+(-1)^3}=\sqrt[3]{(n+(-1))^3}$.